# What type of USB 2.0 connector is this?

Tags: usb

I'm converting lots of USB card readers to be mounted directly on the tablets. One (relatively trivial) problem is that the readers come with long 6ft USB cables which I'd like to shorten to about 1ft so they don't need to be "coiled". I can either splice the cable or hope to buy a pre-made shorter ones. For the latter, I'm not sure how to search for the cable that would have the pictured connector for my mini-boards. From the image, can you tell the connector type I need?

To the best of my abilities, the pitch distance is 1.18mm.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It's not a USB connector per-say. You'd need to take some measurements (pin pitch, connector size, etc.) and take a photo of it with the connector and socket unplugged so we can get an idea of what the pins look like.

Comment: Turns out unplugging it isn't working well. It appears locked in there. So, another question -- if you had to splice 1000 USB cables, what butt connectors would you recommend?

Comment: It looks as though squeezing the sides of the plug may disengage the locking mechanism, although it's difficult to be sure with only the single photo. Also, what is the pin pitch?

Comment: Try harder ... Splicing USB2 cables reliably is not a trivial task.

Comment: OK, the trick was to pull on both ends at the same time. It came out pretty easy that way. I added more photos with some measurements (mm). Let me know if helpful.

Answer (score 1):

That is very likely one of the family of "JST" connectors. They are made in several sizes (pitch distance from pin-to-pin).  Nothing to do with USB.

If you need 1000 cables, you can probably get them fabricated for you as long as you can properly identify exactly which JST connector it is.  Splicing the wire for 1000 cables is NOT RECOMMENDED.

What do you mean by "unplugging it isn't working well"?  It doesn't appear to be glued in from your photo. Of course you won't be able disconnect it until you remove that cable-tie holding the wire.

Comment: Op didn't press both clips. He finally got it loose, no need to cut the strain relief cable tie off. See their updated picture.